# Making a polycube

Tags: modeling

I'd like to make a polycube. That is, I want to create an object which is composed of cubes which share faces. For example:

[image]

I first tried simply taking cubes and sticking them close together, the the resulting mesh data does not correspond to a polycube, as these cubes would not be sharing a side. I then tried taking a rectangular prism and using the loop cut and slide tool, but this would require the prism to be dividable into equal sized cubes (which I wasn't sure how to enforce). Furthermore, I don't see how I could make certain figures (such as the bottom left one from the picture) using this method.

Is there an efficient way of building such polycubes? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If the cubes would share faces it would be considered a non-manifold geometry where 3 faces share an edge. This is not advisable and  considered a rather wrong construct of a mesh, maybe you can elaborate why this is needed vs cubes not sharing faces inside

Comment: Have you tried just extruding the faces of a cube?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply extrude the default cube.
Turning on *Grid Snapping* will make it a fast and easy process.

[image]

Comment: Or simply in edit mode select a face, press "e" for "extrude" and the press "1" to set that extrusion has to be "1 unit" long.

Answer (score 4):

1. Default Plane, Edit Mode, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> scale,  Right-click > *Subdivide*,
   enter 11 cuts.
2. Select ground-floor shapes.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, invert selection, and <kbd>X</kbd> delete faces.
4. All selected, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> extrude.
5. 2nd-floor faces selected, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> extrude.

[image]

6. <kbd>P</kbd> > Separate by loose parts...

[image]

... and possibly, all objects selected,  *Header > Object > Set Origin to*.. Geometry?.. and maybe pick colors from your reference using the eyedropper.